# PHP/SQL ID Based On Alpha Code

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

It will probably help if I precede the information with this: *It is a stock shareholder database. New rows/lines would equal new shareholders in a company. Each shareholder in the old system has what is called a shareholder number and is exactly six characters long with preceding zeros.*

And my direct question is: *How do I give all the new inserted rows unique ID's that will also be alphabetized based on one of the rows.
I need to insert new names and have their ID's be in the same order as the names are alphabetically.*

**Details:**

I'm importing a database from decades ago into a new PHP program. When a row was added in the old system, it took a persons name, linked it with a number, and put it in. The problematic thing is that the entire alphabetic system is sorted by ID instead of directly from the names.

Basically, somebody with the last name "Afrebos" would have an ID like 032500; And somebody with the last name "Williams" would have an ID like 895573; And somebody with the last name "Zeta" would be 985000. The DB doesn't seem to know the alphabet and is completely reliant on the order of the ID numbers.

The new system I'm making will sort by name and would not need these numbers anymore. However, my boss wants to continue using these old numbers(they correlate to other companies systems). I could just choose random unique numbers from now on when rows are added, but for cleanliness and professionalism sake I would like to continue having everything organized in the way it has been for years.

Any ideas on how I can do this with PHP/SQL/PDO? Any help at all would be very appreciated.

Comment: `<?php # code goes here ?>`. the rest is up to you.

Comment: Put an index on whichever column you want to sort your data by without deleting anything, period.

Comment: It sounds like your old table column is a primary key that has outlived its usefulness. Just add a new column with `auto_increment`, and then make the new column the primary key. Keep the old column so you can carry on using it if you wish, and you can make it nullable so new customers do not need it. Most of this depends on what the business requires, I think.

Comment: "I need to insert new names and have their ID's be in the same order as the names are alphabetically" - no, I don't think you do. You should not care about what order the names are in your database, nor what primary key is assigned to what name. If you want to order by names, then order by names in a query, and if you want to order by how long a customer has been in the database, order by created date in a query, etc. As I describe, maintaining the legacy number in a non-primary key field is the way to go.

Comment: I actually do need them to be that way. For reasons I didn't go into I do need them to maintain their order and ordering style. That's the whole point of this question.

Answer (score 2):

SQL can quickly sort by varchar columns such as names (i.e. in alphabetical order), especially if you index that column.

I would alter your table to include an auto-increment id and store the old id in a separate column, even a separate table if new entries will not require a comparable id, but you could just as well keep the original ids as your primary key column and pick a random unused value for each new entry.